# node.js handling stream back pressure when using setTimeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, concurrency

This is a follow on question for a further issue I've encountered from this earlier question:

[nodejs: read from file and store to db, limit maximum concurrent db operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098022/nodejs-read-from-file-and-store-to-db-limit-maximum-concurrent-db-operations)

**Problem:**

I want to condtionally reschedule some operations for a later time, however this is breaking my method for handling back-pressure.

**Detail:**

I have a CSV file that I am reading in as a stream, and using transforms to convert to JSON and then asynchronously store each line to a DB.

As lines are processed by the transform, they are placed onto an async queue which is responsible for issuing the DB operations.

E.g.

```
parser._transform = function(data, encoding, done) {

    var tick = this._parseRow(data);

    dbQueue.push(tick, function(err, result) {
      if (typeof(err) != 'undefined') { console.log(err) }
    });

    this.push(tick);
    done();
}
```

Back pressure is handled by pausing and resuming the parser when the queue is saturated/empty:

```
dbQueue.saturated = function() {
  parser.pause();
}

dbQueue.empty = function() {
  parser.resume();
}
```

The change I have been trying to make is that when an item is pulled off the queue, it is conditionally rescheduled for some time (100ms) in future:

```
var dbQueue = async.queue(function(data, callback) {
  if (condition) {
    // re-schedule operation by adding back to queue 100ms later
    setTimeout(function(data, callback) {
        dbQueue.push(data, function(err, result){
      });
    }, 100, data, callback);
  } else {
    //execute the db store
     ... ...
  }
}
```

I believe my problem is that now many operations will spend most their time in setTimeout, so the dbQueue will be empty, and the back-pressure on the transform stream is not being handled as desired.

I have tried a few attempts at using counters such as max_ops and running_ops to ensure the stream is paused/resumed, but unsuccessfully.

Is there a more idiomatic way of handling this in node.js?

Comment: are you doing batch inserts into the DB or one by one?  Which DB and driver are you using - I'm just curious

Comment: wondering if you can use the c++ port of disruptor in nodejs instead of your implementation - disruptor takes care of back pressure (I know about Java - not sure about the C++ port).  https://github.com/fsaintjacques/disruptor--

Comment: The DB and driver is Couchbase -- in the first case using just the queues and pause/resume of the parser it works extremely well. What i'm really interested in is the right way to go about solving the latter part of the problem with the reschedulings, specifically in node.js.

Comment: What's the condition that you're wanting to reschedule on?  Is there something about it that is preventing you from simply pausing the queue when that condition occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like it's an external condition and not something related to what `dbQueue` is doing, instead of re-inserting the data in to the queue when the condition occurs, I would pause simply pause `dbQueue`. For example, lets say your condition is that the database disconnected for some reason and there's an event you can listen to for that.  In that case you can just do something similar to what you're doing when `dbQueue` is saturated/empty:

```
db.on('disconnect', function() {
    dbQueue.pause();
});

db.on('connect', function() {
    dbQueue.resume();
});
```

This is usually a better approach than waiting for some pre-determined timeout.  That being said, sometimes waiting for a timeout is the only option.  In that case you could do something similar but, instead of waiting for a separate event to trigger the `resume()`, simply use `setTimeout()`:

```
db.on('disconnect', function() {
    dbQueue.pause();
    setTimeout(function() {
        dbQueue.resume();
    });
});
```

*Note: If we are really talking about db disconnects here, then you might also want to pause/resume `dbQueue` if there's a db error in the case that 100ms isn't enough time for the db to re-connect*

If you have a more specific condition you're looking for, and you're willing to share what that is, I may be able to give you a better example :)